# Hide non metro apps from the 'Start Screen' or create a different column for them

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, modern-ui

How can I hide all the non-metro apps (ie: desktop apps) from the Start Screen on Windows 8, they take up a lot of space on the screen.

Also, for an alternative, non-metro apps should **always** be placed in the last. I want that newly installed apps from the Windows Store to come **before** the non-metro apps by default.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tile related to the app and from the App bar that is launched at the bottom, select "Unpin from Start"  to remove the shortcut to the non-metro app.

I guess, you may have to manually group tiles related to non-metro apps and position them at the end as the App bar and the Settings Charm don't seem to have anything to automate your requirement.

Comment: This is not what I want, I want this task to be automated. I want new Metro apps installed to be tiled before non-metro apps.